# Andengine coin pickup nullpointer exception

Tags: android, andengine

I'm new to game development, and tried AndEngine to construct a racing game.
 When My sprite(car) collides with a coin, it plays a sound and disappears.
 I used tiled map editor to load my coin objects.
 The coordinates system in the tiled map editor, which creates the xml for the map and andengine gles 2 - anchor center are inverted.  I thought tmxExtension would handle this conversion.. 
 So far I am calculating each object positions and changing its position in the xml editor to correct the positions. Is there any other easier way ?

Here are my codes for loading the map:

```
private void createLevel() {
    coins = new LinkedList < Sprite > ();
    try {

        final TMXLoader tmxLoader = new TMXLoader(activity.getAssets(), engine.getTextureManager(),
        TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, vbom);

        this.mTMXTiledMap = tmxLoader.loadFromAsset("tmx/uom_map_test2.tmx");
    } catch (final TMXLoadException e) {
        Debug.e(e);
    }

    FixtureDef wallFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(
    0,
    0,
    1,
    camera.getBoundsYMax(),
    vbom);
    Body wall1 = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, rect1, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
    wall1.setUserData(wall1);

    FixtureDef wallFixtureDef2 = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(
    1100,
    0,
    1,
    camera.getBoundsYMax(),
    vbom);
    Body wall2 = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, rect2, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef2);


    for (final TMXObjectGroup group: this.mTMXTiledMap.getTMXObjectGroups()) {
        for (final TMXObject object: group.getTMXObjects()) {

            if (object.getName().equals("coin")) {
                Sprite coin = new Sprite(object.getX(), object.getY(), object.getWidth(), object.getHeight(), resourcesManager.coinTextureRegion, vbom);
                FixtureDef coinFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0.3f, 0.3f);

                Body bod = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, coin, BodyType.DynamicBody, coinFixtureDef);
                bod.setUserData("coin");
                coins.add(coin);
                coin.setUserData(bod);

            } else if (object.getName().equals("sea")) {
                FixtureDef seaFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 0f);
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(
                object.getX(),
                object.getY(),
                object.getWidth(),
                object.getHeight(),
                vbom);

                Body bod = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, rect, BodyType.DynamicBody, seaFixtureDef);
                bod.setUserData("sea");

            }


        }

    }

    /*for(TMXLayer layer : this.mTMXTiledMap.getTMXLayers()){
           layer.detachSelf();
           layer.setPosition(0,0);
           attachChild(layer);*/

    for (int layerID = 0; layerID < this.mTMXTiledMap.getTMXLayers().size(); layerID++) {
        this.mTMXTiledMap.getTMXLayers().get(layerID).detachSelf();
        attachChild(this.mTMXTiledMap.getTMXLayers().get(layerID));

        //       layer0:sea              layer1:grass               layer2:road

        for (int i = 0; i < coins.size(); i++) {
            this.attachChild(coins.get(i));
        }

        camera.setBounds(0, 0, mTMXTiledMap.getWidth(), mTMXTiledMap.getHeight());
        camera.setBoundsEnabled(true);



    }
}
```

Also, I use a contact listener to manage coin collisions

```
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    Body a = null, b = null;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        a = contact.getFixtureA().getBody();
        b = contact.getFixtureB().getBody();
    } catch (NullPointerException n) {
        //do nothing
    }

    if (a != null && b != null) {

        if (a.getUserData() != null && b.getUserData() != null) {
            if (a.getUserData().equals("player") && b.getUserData().equals("coin") || b.getUserData().equals("player") && a.getUserData().equals("coin")) {

                if (a.getUserData().equals("coin")) {
                    removeCoins(a);
                    resourcesManager.coinCollect.play();
                    addToScore(10);
                    showLevelCleared();
                } else if (b.getUserData().equals("coin")) {
                    removeCoins(b);
                    resourcesManager.coinCollect.play();
                    addToScore(5);
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

However not all coins' collisions are detected.  I get a null pointerException for those, that's why I included a catch.
Any reason for this?

Comment: Can you include the logcat please?

Comment: tim687: for the coin detection i changed the code and instead of creating bodies and removing the bodies on collision with player, i used a timer handler and checks collsions with player.collideswith(coin) , and it works perfectly..
 However, i still couldnt find an easier solution for the coordinates conversion in GLes 2-anchor centre.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest instead of creating a seperate timerhandler to check for collision, do all these in onManagedUpdate